# Useradd command input

Tags: useradd

If you add a user using useradd you get asked to supply some other information about the user (Full name, room number, work phone etc).

Where exactly is this information being stored?
How do you access this information?
How do you edit this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [GECOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field) data, and are stored in `/etc/passwd`, in the fifth field as a set of comma-separated values:

```
$ getent passwd pulse
pulse:x:115:122:PulseAudio daemon,,,:/var/run/pulse:/bin/false
```

They can be modified using the [`chfn`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/chfn) command (preferably), or the [`usermod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/usermod) command.

I don't know if there are utilities to get a particular field directly, but you can parse the output of [`getent passwd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/getent) or [`finger`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/finger).

Answer (score 1):

The extra information is stored in the `/etc/passwd` file. Check it out:

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

To edit this information use the `chfn` command.

Answer (score 1):

Its all in the `/etc/passwd` file. There, you can see all the accounts that exist on your Linux system and, the different fields that describe different things. By default, the `/etc/passwd` file has several entries about the root account and user accounts that were created at time of installation.

You can view the info using the [finger](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_finger.htm) command, and modify it using the [chfn](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_chfn.htm) command.  Also you can use the User Accounts entry to modify that info as well.

[image]